# how to create design like this in windows phone universal project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

[how can i design following?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU6MU.png)

what i have tried so far :

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Image Source="{Binding nexs}" Width="70" Height="70" Grid.Column="0"/>  

   <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
      <Image Source="{Binding url}" Height="{Binding height}" Width="{Binding width}"/>
   </Grid>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Foreground="Black" />                                                             
</Grid>
```

is there anyway 2 to put rows inside columdefinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can have columdefinations and rowdefinations. If you want multiple rows in a column then create another grid and set the row definitions on that grid.
Or, create rows and columns definitions on main grid and set row spans on controls to get the desired layout.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Image Source="{Binding nexs}" Width="70" Height="70" Grid.Column="0"/>  

   <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
      <Image Source="{Binding url}" Height="{Binding height}" Width="{Binding width}"/>
   </Grid>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Foreground="Black" />         

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Place controls here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```